# .NET Web API AuthenticateAsync leaves context User Unauthenticated

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to allow users and internal APIs to consume my Web Service.
So the users will come in with JWT which is working fine.

Now I'd like to give the internal APIs access as well, but the shall only be able to access a part of the function set.

Here is what I've done:
I created a middleware on just the paths, that should be accessible, like so:

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/internals", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), app =>
{
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Method == "GET")
        {
            var header = ctx.Request.Headers[MyConstants.API_HEADER];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header))
            {
                await ctx.AuthenticateAsync(MyConstants.API_HEADER);
            }
        }
        await next();
    });
});
```

The AuthenticationHandler is executed and returns a `AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, this.Scheme.Name))`.

My expectation would be, that the user in: `ctx.User.Identity` should be set to the principal, that I've defined in the `AuthenticationTicket`.

Side note: If I look into the principal, that I serve to the `AuthentictionTicket` it says it is authenticated.